# ADAL Azure Active Directory SignOut Redirect URL not working anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Implemented authentication for my web-app with azure AD 5 weeks ago, had a few initial problems whereby if a user had cached credentials from another directory (in this case my university's) the signin wouldn't work properly. The solution was to implement the following code:

```
public void SignIn(bool? signedOut)
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the user is currently logged into another directory, log them out then attempt to
            // reauthenticate under this directory
            if (signedOut == null || signedOut == false)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { signedOut = true }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme) },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("Dashboard", "User", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme) },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
    }
```

What this essentially does is force the user to signout then immediately sign back in, the process really only takes about 1.5 seconds so it seemed like  a neat solution to wipe any cached credentials. This has been working for the past 5 weeks but has all of a sudden stopped working on both my test and live systems. Signout will work without fault but the redirect back to the signin url doesn't kick in, hence stranding the user on the screen in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BwVO.png). You can view the specified site [here](https://taskboardcln.azurewebsites.net/), the issue presents itself when you click the Sign In button.

After double checking source control, I can confirm that any changes that I have made to the code recently cannot have caused the issue, it almost appears as if there has been a change in the way that microsoft handles things on their side.

Architecture: Azure Web App running on .NET 4.5

Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to let me know if I can provide anymore useful information,

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: So let me get this straight. In the SignIn action, if the user is not authenticated, and the signedOut query parameter is not given, you sign them out. So a user who is not even signed in yet is signed out?

Comment: Yeah this is right, I need to do it this way so that if the user has already signed into a different directory (their personal outlook or university email etc.), those credentials will be wiped before going through the sign-in process. Missing this step will sometimes prompt AD to try and use an existing cached credential as far as I can tell.

Comment: Now that I looked at the screen shot, I've seen that before. But I really do not know what causes that. Though have you tried including the client id in the request? Since now there is only the redirect URI. Azure AD might be deciding it's safer to keep the user there rather than send it to some URL that it doesn't know if it is a reply URL for an app.

Comment: Can confirm that after including the clientid in the request that it hasn't made a difference unfortunately, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be the problem that you're facing locally, but I had problems when I've published to Azure, because it was overwriting my ida:Audience  setting. Take a look at your web.config using Kudu and see if it is still as you want.

[Azure AD + ADAL.js + App Service - Only one claim on ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411761/azure-ad-adal-js-app-service-only-one-claim-on-claimsprincipal-current-cla)